# Line up Column B and its Value in Column C with Column A values retaining original order of column A. Puts non-matching column B values below

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Please can anyone help out me doing this?

I have two main columns A and B. Column A contains a product code and column B contain its price. Now I have some product code in column C. I need their prices and maintain column C order.

```
 A    B    C   D    
110  $10  115  
111  $12  120
112  $18  117
113  $13  111
114  $22
115  $24
116  $98
117  $26
118  $77
119  $34
120  $17
```

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Therefore please show what you already have tried. [Edit] your question, add your code and ask a specific question to it. Also your question is very unclear to me so you might also read [ask].

Comment: You should read about the VLOOKUP function, e.g. [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). Write some code and come back if your code fails.

Comment: How does your question relate to programming? If you don't know how to use an Excel function for a lookup, this does not belong here. Post on Superuser.com instead, where software usage is disussed.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula in `Column D` and drag it down,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C1,A:A,0),1),"")
```

[image]